# String templates in R

Tags: r, string, templates

R's {glue} package does what Python's f-strings do. Does R have anything, either in the base language or a package, that does what Python's [template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) do?

Python 3 example:

```py
from string import Template
# Define variables in the template string
s = Template('$who likes $what')
# Assign variable values outside of the template string
person = 'tim'
thing = 'kung pao'
s.substitute(who=person, what=thing)
# 'tim likes kung pao'
```

I found the [{templates}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/templates/) package, but it's old, it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, and there's no git repo or site given so I can submit bug reports or contribute.

Base R's `sprintf()` doesn't satisfy my requirements.

I know about {reticulate}. I want to know if string templates are possible in R at all, without getting Python involved.

Comment: what about `str_interp` from the `stringr` package

Comment: @GordonShumway, This is the answer. If you submit a proper answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, provided by commenter @GordonShumway, is `stringr::str_interp()`. I missed the template example in the documentation.

```r
library(stringr)

s = "${who} likes ${what}"
person = "tim"
thing = "kung pao"
stringr::str_interp(s, list(who=person, what=thing))
# "tim likes kung pao"
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) below addresses the precise syntax in the question while (2) and (3) are variations.

**1) gsubfn** The `gsubfn` in the package of the same name with the default pattern (first argument) can do that.  It is a superset of `gsub` where the replacement (second argument) can be a string (like `gsub`), list, function or proto object.  Using $ requires that the string be such that it can detect the end of the word after $ but if not the string can be surrounded by backticks.

The pattern argument (first argument) can be specified if you want different sorts of matches.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(, list(who = "person", what = "thing"), '$who likes $what')
## [1] "person likes thing"
```

**2) fn$** There is also `fn$` in the same package which is often used with sqldf package but is not specific to it.  It allows string interpolation in arguments to a function if the function call is prefaced with `fn$` .

```
who <- "person"; what <- "thing"
fn$c("$who likes $what")
## [1] "person likes thing"
```

**2a)** which could be written as shown to limit the scope of `who` and `what`.

```
local({
  who <- "person"; what <- "thing"
  fn$c("$who likes $what")
})
## [1] "person likes thing"
```

**3) sprintf** The base of R supports `sprintf` which is positional rather than keyword oriented:

```
sprintf("%s likes %s", "person", "thing")
## [1] "person likes thing"
```